# GlideAjax is not defined in UI macro

Tags: macros, servicenow, jelly

I'm calling GlideAjax from UI Macro , but I'm facing below error:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: "GlideAjax" is not defined.
Caused by error in at line 2

1:
==> 2: var ga = new GlideAjax('global.GetHostName');
3: ga.getXMLWait();
4: var hostName = ga.getAnswer();
5:
```

My UI Macro looks like below:

```
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
<g:evaluate>
var ga = new GlideAjax('global.GetHostName');
ga.getXMLWait();
var hostName = ga.getAnswer(); 

</g:evaluate>
<!--<j:set var="jvar_inc" value="${help_sysid}" />-->
   <span id="asp-cms-user-salutation">
      ${gs.getMessage('Welcome')},
      <j:if test="${!gs.getUser().isXML()}">
         <span id="asp-cms-user-name"><a href="profile.do">${gs.getUserDisplayName()}</a></span>
<span id="asp-cms-user-sysname">${hostName}</span>
      </j:if>

   </span>


</j:jelly>
```

What I'm doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GlideAjax` is a client-side api used to make your browser make an ajax request.
The `<g:evaluate>` tag in jelly is a server-side script. Assuming `GetHostName` is a Script include name, you can just directly call the script include like:

```
<g:evaluate>
var hostNameGetter = new global.GetHostName();
var hostName = hostNameGetter.getValue(); // replace getValue() with whatever your method name is in GetHostname
</g:evaluate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, Is this possible to display computer name of end user dynamically on ess page ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get a client's computer host name from pure javascript.